# Connecting flask app to mysql on kubernetes

Tags: python, mysql, flask, kubernetes

I have a MySQL container running on a Kube cluster and a flask app running on my local machine (which I eventually also plan to upload onto the kube cluster). How can I connect my flask app to the database? So far I have tried changing the host to the IP address of the Kube cluster.

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(
    host=host_ip,
    user="root",
    passwd="password",
    db="flaskapp")
```

Just to reiterate, the flask application is running on my local machine. I can connect to a database that I run locally, but I'm not sure how to connect it to a database run on a Kube cluster, on a different machine.

Comment: In the development phase I'd recommend using [Telepresence](https://www.telepresence.io/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use PyMySQL to connect to any DB, locally or online.

https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: What exactly would I use at the `hostname`? I'm now using `pymysql.connect(host=host_ip...`.Using the ip address alone doesn't seem to work. Do I need to use a kubernetes service?

Comment: check your kubernets service , you will have the mysql instance details .. it should work.. and make sure you pass the host ip as string.

Comment: My kubernetes service looks like this:
`mysql                               None            <none>        3306/TCP       7d` The only info I have is the port. There is no cluster IP or external IP.

Comment: Get the IP address of one of the Nodes and the NodePort for the web Service. Populate the variables with the appropriate values

kubectl get nodes
kubectl describe svc web

kubectl get nodes
export NODE_IP=<NODE_IP>
export NODE_PORT=<NODE_PORT> Source link : [link](https://github.com/janakiramm/Kubernetes-multi-container-pod#get-the-ip-address-of-one-of-the-nodes-and-the-nodeport-for-the-web-service-populate-the-variables-with-the-appropriate-values)